# How to setup replication on Artifactory OSS version

Tags: maven, artifactory, devops

I have 2 Artifactory-OSS servers, both are placed at 2 different location. I want to enable replication for maven repositories created on this servers, so could anyone has done this kind of setup to enable replication feature on artifactory-oss version?

Comment: Replication feature is not available in Artifactory-OSS version.

Comment: Yes I know that replication feature is not available in Artifactory-OSS version, but is there any way to do replication by syncing data directories of both artifactory servers?

Answer (score 1):

[Repository replication](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Repository+Replication) requires at least an Artifactory [Pro](https://jfrog.com/pricing/) license.
You can create a [remote repository](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Remote+Repositories) in one Artifactory which point to a local repository on the other Artifactory. This will enable you to cache files located in the remote Artifactory. Caching will be performed only when the artifact is requested, as opposed to replication which will actively populate the artifacts.

The Artifactory Pro version supports the following types of replications:

1. **Scheduled push replication** - Push replication is used to synchronize Local Repositories, and is implemented by the Artifactory server on the near end invoking a synchronization of artifacts to the far end. Pushes are scheduled asynchronously at regular intervals.
2. **Event based push replication** - Pushes occur in nearly in real-time since each create, copy, move or delete of an artifact is immediately propagated to the far end
3. **Scheduled pull replication** - This provides a way to proactively populate a remote cache, and is useful when waiting for new artifacts to arrive on demand (when first requested) is not desirable due to network latency. Pull replication is invoked by a remote repository, and runs asynchronously according to a defined schedule to synchronize repositories (local, remote or virtual) at regular intervals.

The Artifactory Enterprise version supports the following additional types of replications:

1. **Event based pull replication** - Pulls occur nearly in real-time since each create, copy, move or delete of an artifact is immediately propagated to the far end. As soon as a file is uploaded it is replicated and immediately available to the target (pulling) instance without even having to wait for the file upload to be completed at the source
2. **Multi push replication** - replicate a local repository from a single source to multiple enterprise target sites simultaneously

The [replication](https://jfrog.com/whitepaper/replication-using-artifactory-to-manage-binaries-across-multi-site-topologies/) white paper describes how to use replication to support different types of topologies like star and full mesh.

Comment: I have checked Artifactory Pro version, but as mentioned on Jfrog artifactory website, pro also not support multi site replication. so could you please help me to understand how Artifactory Pro version support replication?

Comment: @NileshAttarde I updated the answer with more information and a reference to the replication white paper